# $X⊆Z$ and $Y⊆Z$ then $X∪Y⊆Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please help me prove this? I've been trying for a while now but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I proved that if $X ⊆ Y$, then $P(X) ⊆ P(Y)$ but I am struggling with this one. Would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Hint: Let $a\in X\cup Y$. What can you say about $a$?

Comment: Hint: disjunction elimination

Comment: a would be in both X and Y?

Comment: @xdef if $a$ is in both $X$ and $Y$, then $a$ is in their intersection, not their union.

Comment: Maybe if you try showing that if
$X\cap Y \nsubseteq Z,$ then $X\nsubseteq Z$ or $Y\nsubseteq Z.$

Comment: @xdef You can say $a \in X$ **or** $a \in Y$. This suggests that you might want to split into two cases. What if $a \in X$, for example? What do your hypotheses tell you about elements of $X$ in relation to $Z$?